# Please explain me this python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

**mipText** is any Binary string

**keys** like: (48, 34, 65, 168, 91, nn)

And please explain me code below

```
def test(mipText,keys):
    mipText = list(mipText)
    for i, encryptedChar in enumerate(mipText):
        mipText[i] = encryptedChar ^ keys[i & 0xFF]
    return mipText
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Fix your indentation and format your code properly

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is "encryptedChar ^ keys[i & 0xFF]"

Comment: Can you tell us what specifically you want to know? This question is hopelessly vague.

Comment: @Maulwurfn fixed indentation, thank you

Comment: And use a reasonable subject. This alone deserves a downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a list out of the contents of a file

eg.
"Hello Word" after unpack becomes [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100]

then it XORS each index with a value from key (eg. 0b010101 ^ 0b110011 = '0b100110')

`i&0xFF` just ensures the index of keys will never be greater than 0xff (255) ...basically the same as `i%256` only faster

Answer (score 1):

It encrypts (or decrypts, it doesn't matter) the `mipText` with the [simple XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) using the supplied `keys` key with the length of 256 bytes.

`keys[i & 0xFF]` is the appropriate key byte (located in `keys` on the `i mod 256`th position).

`encryptedChar ^ keys[i & 0xFF]` XORs the `i`th byte of the original `mipText` string with the appropriate key byte.

`mipText[i] = encryptedChar ^ keys[i & 0xFF]` replaces the `i`th byte of the original `mipText` string with the encrypted version of the byte.

Note that, as two applications of `XOR` yield the original result, the algorithm is symmetric: if supplied an original string, it encrypts it; if supplied an encrypted string, it decrypts it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 keys[i & 0xFF]
```

return the i-th value of a 256-byte key string.

This value is then XOR-ed with the related encrypted character (^ = XOR)